# Определение нажатия системных кнопок Android

Tags: android

Как известно, в Android есть 3 системные кнопки (закладки, главный экран, назад).

Можно ли как-то в коде приложения определить, какая из них была нажата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Кнопку Back можно:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       // your code.
   }
   ```
2. Home со 100% уверенностью никак. Формально, когда пользователь жмёт Home, то сработает `onStop`:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
      // скорей всего юзер нажал кнопку Home
   }
   ```

   Но это не всегда верно.
3. Recent вроде тоже по-нормальному не отловить. Нашёл только [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773533/1991579) хак.